# Problem with power series problem.

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

Using this theorem:

> Let $(a_k)$ be a sequence in $\Bbb R$ and let $x_0\in \Bbb R$:
>
> - The power series: $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k(x-x_0)^k \qquad \text{and} \qquad \sum_{k=0}^\infty ka_k(x-x_0)^{k-1} $$ converge uniformly in $[x_0-r,x_0+r]$ for all $r\in (0,R)$ where $R$ is the radius of convergence of $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k(x-x_0)^k $.
> - The function $$f(x):= \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k(x-x_0)^k $$ is continously diferentiable in $(x_0-R,x_0+R)$, and its derivative is given by: $$f'(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty ka_k(x-x_0)^{k-1} $$

calculate the following: $$\tag {1} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac {k}{2^{k-1}}$$

---

So, I'm confused on what do I have to do. I'm *gessing* that we have to find the $x_0$ of this: $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac {k}{2^{k-1}} (x-x_0)^k$$
I know that $\mathbf {(1)}$ converges to $4$, but I didn't used the theorem, and using the definition of radius of convergence, (superficially) I found that $R:=\sup\{r\in(-2,2) \mid \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac {k}{2^{k-1}}r^k<\infty \text{ (the sum converges in $\Bbb R$)} \}$.
I don't see what they're asking me to do, and why/how to use the theorem.

Comment: The question is asking "to what value does $(1)$ converge?"  But, how do you know that it converges to $4$?  The formula you probably used is the *derivative* of the geometric series formula...  And, derivatives are in that theorem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Take $x = 1/2$ and $x_0 = 0$.   $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^\infty k (x - x_0)^{k-1}$ is the derivative of ...

Comment: Yesterday I put a comment, but now is not important and I don't think it contributes anything, that's why I deleted it. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

First, recall that for values of $|x|<1$ one has that the geometric series
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k
$$
is uniformly convergent so that one can interchange multiplications and derivatives with the series.

Then, from the property $$x\frac{d}{dx}(x^k)=kx^k$$
there holds that that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty kx^k=x\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}.
$$
yields by term-by-term aplication of the operator $x\frac{d}{dx}$ to the coefficients of the series expansion.

In particular, for $x=\frac{1}{2}$
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k}{2^k}=2.
$$

Hence,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k}{2^{k-1}}=2
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k}{2^{k}}=4.
$$